# Nginx SSL termination proxy to Nexus not working with ports different than 443

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nexus

I have a Nginx working as a SSL termination reverse proxy for a Nexus repository.

This is the configuration:

```
server {
    server_name nexus.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nexus.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nexus.example.com/privkey.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    client_max_body_size 1G;

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* docker) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure; HttpOnly";

        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/nexus_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nexus_error.log;
}
```

That's working fine with no problems. However, I want to expose the Nginx in a different port, let's say 10000. If I change the configuration and restart both Nginx and Nexus, whenever I visit `nexus.example.com:10000` I get multiple errors because the browser is doing requests to resources on `https://nexus.example.com` (without the port).

I thought it might be a caching issue, so I tried in incognito mode, but it didn't work either. Tried with a brand new virtual machine, same problem, so I discard the cache issue.

If I expose the Nexus directly on nexus.example.com:8081, it works as well.

What might be wrong?

I tried the following workaround, but although I'm able to reach the Nexus front-page, I can't log in.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nexus.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nexus.example.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host:10000$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the port into the host header: proxy_set_header Host $host:10000;

Comment: @rseddon I doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met the same problem.
Change `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to
`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` solve it

Comment: it doesn't work for me, that's the same suggestion @rseddon said in the comment

Comment: This does work and helped as i was accessing it on different port

Answer (score 2):

for reference - this is working for me:

```
upstream origin {
    server nexus:8081;
}

server {
    listen 8084 ssl http2;
    server_name nexus.mydoman.tld;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mydomain.tld.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mydomain.tld.key;


    # https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr:8084;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 8084;
        proxy_pass http://origin;
    }

}
```

Thanks to @Ying Yi & @rseddon

Comment: This works for me. To make it a bit cleaner: X-Forwarded-Port can be removed and port from X-Real-IP can be also removed (because it's IP)